# How to setup alias parameter in apscheduler config?

Tags: apscheduler

There is a question about setup config. Can I set a parameter `alias`, when use `config` method to setup `executers` and `jobstores`, which likes that use the `add_jobstore` method with `alias` paramter

```
# scheduler add_jobstore
scheduler.add_jobstore(jobstore_type, alias=alias, **config)
```

When I setup the `alias` in **config**, get TypeError: unexpected keyword argument `alias`. Below it's my configuration:

```
{
    "executors": {
         ...
        }
    },
    "jobstores": {
        "apscheduler.jobstores.redis":{
            "class": "apscheduler.jobstores.redis:RedisJobStore",
            ...
            "socket_timeout": 5,
            "alias": "Test" # here set a alias
        },
        "apscheduler.jobstores.mongo": {
            "class": "apscheduler.jobstores.mongodb:MongoDBJobStore",
            ...
            "minPoolSize":20
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fix the problem. The `jobstores` , `executers` alias value should be declare at begining.

```
There is a question about setup config. Can I set a parameter alias, when use config method to setup executers and jobstores, which likes that use the add_jobstore method with alias paramter

# scheduler add_jobstore
scheduler.add_jobstore(jobstore_type, alias=alias, **config)
When I setup the alias in config, get TypeError: unexpected keyword argument alias. Below it's my configuration:

{
    "executors": {
         ...
        }
    },
    "jobstores": {
        "redis":{
            "class": "apscheduler.jobstores.redis:RedisJobStore",
            ...
            "socket_timeout": 5,
        },
        "mongo": {
            "class": "apscheduler.jobstores.mongodb:MongoDBJobStore",
            ...
            "minPoolSize":20
        }
    }
}
```

If like this, `scheduler` will get the `jobstore` keyes are `redis` and `mongo` those are the alias values.